# XPath select second element of many unless only one exists

Tags: html, xpath

I have a webpage with three `<input>` elements that all have the same `name` attribute. Ideally, I would like to select the second of these elements except sometimes there is only one element on the page and I want to instead select that element.

Ideally I would like something like (pseudo-code since `max` doesn't exist)

```
(//input[@name='myname'])[max(1, last()-1)]
```

I thought that maybe I could do something like the following except it yields all three elements

```
(//input[@name='myname'])[last()-1 or 1]
```

What is the best way to accomplish this using XPath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe grab both and then only the last one.

If there's two or more, it gets the second. If there's only one, it grabs that one.

```
((//input[@name='myname'])[position()=1 or position()=2])[last()]
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks like it should work. I guess I didn't understand that I needed to use `position()` rather than just `[1 or 2]`. I thought that an integer was implicitly treated as `position() = N`

Comment: @Suever - You're welcome. Also, your first XPath would work if you were able to use XPath 2.0 and passed a sequence to [`max()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-xpath-functions-20101214/#func-max)...`(//input[@name='myname'])[max((1, last()-1))]`

Comment: @Suever: an integer N is only treated as (position()=N) when the entire predicate is an integer. But in 2.0 you can write `[position() = 1 to 2]`. And in 1.0 you can write `[position() &lt;= 2]`